# Problem in bulk load from a file into Cassandra using phpcassa

Tags: php, cassandra, phpcassa

I am trying to load 1000000 records from a text file into [Cassandra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Cassandra) using phpcassa. But halfway through the loading process I got the following error.

> PHP Fatal error:  Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in /usr/share/php/phpcassa/columnfamily.php on line 759**

How do I increase the execution time? Do I have to change any parameter in `columnfamily.php`?
Please find my code below.

```
 <?
     require_once('phpcassa/connection.php');
     require_once('phpcassa/columnfamily.php');
     try {
     $servers = array("127.0.0.1:9160");
     $pool = new ConnectionPool("Keyspace1", $servers);
     $column_family = new ColumnFamily($pool, 'Product');
     $cnt=0;
     $files = fopen("dump.txt", "r");

     $mtime = microtime();
     $mtime = explode(" ",$mtime);
     $mtime = $mtime[1] + $mtime[0];
     $starttime = $mtime;

     while (!feof($files)) {
         $line = fgets($files);
         $keyname="P".$cnt;
         $split_line = explode("," , $line);
         for ($i=0;$i<count($split_line);$i++) {
             //echo $split_line[$i];
             $column_family->insert(
                 $keyname, array(
                     'code' => $split_line[0] ,
                     'pname' => $split_line[1] ,
                     'price' => $split_line[2]
                 )
             );
         }
         $cnt += 1;
     }
     $mtime = microtime();
     $mtime = explode(" ",$mtime);
     $mtime = $mtime[1] + $mtime[0];
     $endtime = $mtime;

     fclose($files);

     $totaltime = ($endtime - $starttime);
     echo "$cnt keys loaded in ".$totaltime." seconds";

     }
     catch (Exception $e)
     {
         echo 'Exception: ' . $e->getMessage();
     }
 ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try and add this to top of your script:

`set_time_limit(0);`

Answer (score 0):

See *[set_time_limit](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php)*.

More generally, doing bulk load inside a web server environment (that's what this is, right?) isn't the best idea. Neither is doing it with a single thread. But for just a million rows this will work adequately, I guess.

Answer (score 0):

Please increase the `max_execution_time` limit in `php.ini` file.
This will avoid `PHP Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds`.
By default, the maximum execution time on web servers remains at 30 seconds.

You can change that amount to provide more time for certain executions on your server.

```
max_execution_time = 1200;
```