# How I translate mysql database/table data to cassandra data files...?

Tags: mysql, migration, cassandra

I have a large database in MySQL and it is about 4 Gb, still increasing day by day. Because of this, I'm going to migrate to Cassandra. But I don't have any idea how to convert the MySQL files to Cassandra hash files. There is no GUI for Cassandra, like PHPMyAdmin.

How should I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cassandra is very different from MySQL. It's not just another relational database.  It's designed to deal with datasets that do not fit in memory on a single machine.

For 4GB of data you have a lot of options. Redis. MongoDB. MySQL. These will all be fine, given appropriate hardware.

So I'd say that "How do I get this in Cassandra [or other Hot New Technology]?" is the wrong question. "How do I tune my MySQL database" is the right question, and/or, "What hardware should I buy or rent so I don't have this pain point?"

Comment: Hi Jbellis ..I found a solution for this ..I converted the .sql files to csv fomat by /t(tab) then found a code from [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6224394/problem-in-bulk-load-from-a-file-into-cassandra-using-phpcassa](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6224394/problem-in-bulk-load-from-a-file-into-cassandra-using-phpcassa) and customised it.Then exported the sql files to cassandra...